# Database Engines and ANSI SQL Compliance

Tags: sql, database, standards, ansi-sql

I've been searching for half an hour and can't find any resources stating what level of the SQL ANSI standard is supported on various database engines.

It looks like some level of support is provided by most engines, but I'd like to know *exactly* what level is officially supported.

I'm primarily interested in MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQL Server, and Oracle.

EDIT: PostgreSQL has a great page on compliance, exactly what I was looking for regarding the other engines: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/features.html

Comment: ANSI support depends on specific versions of the database products you listed, so it'd help us if you can clarify.  This is a very broad question...

Comment: I am interested in the latest version of each product. However, I couldn't find ANSI compliance information even without restricting my research to a specific version.

Comment: ANSI-89 would be the fundamental level.  After that, it's not wholesale support--just features & functions as seen fit.

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/ap_standard_sql.htm

Answer (score 16):

these might help a little:

[Comparison of different SQL implementations](http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/)

[wikipedia - Comparison of relational database management systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems)

[wikipedia - SQL - Standardization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql#Standardization)

Answer (score 6):

The question of "which level of the standard" is too simple.

There are portions of the standard that are implemented by no engine at all, e.g. CREATE ASSERTION.

For that reason, it might be better to speak of "percentage of standard features supported" for each individual engine.  But the vendors will be very reluctant to publish such measurements themselves.

Answer (score 2):

The PostgreSQL manual has for [all SQL statements](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-alterrole.html) a compatibility section.

Answer (score 2):

According to the HSQLDB manual, [it is the most standards compliant RDBMS](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/sqlgeneral-chapt.html#sgc_standards).

- Almost all syntactic features of SQL-92 up to Advanced Level are supported
- SQL:2008 core and many optional features of this standard

Comment: " supports the widest range of SQL standard features among all open source RDBMS."

Comment: Other comparisons that actually list the features such as here: http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/ (granted it needs to be updated), have SQL Server as the least compliant. Which makes one wonder what standard they are talking about in your quote?

Comment: @markmnl This answer is about HSQLDB, not SQL Server. The guide you're quoting doesn't even mention HSQLDB. Which makes one wonder what you're talking about? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Firebird 3 sql [standard conformance](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/sql-conformance/) page